# What is better in Google Cloud? Projects or Instance of vm for every customers?

Tags: virtual-machine, instance, google-cloud-platform

I'm a web developer and mobile applications. I have several clients which I manage in a hosting service with whm panel. Now I want to start using Google Cloud. My question is whether it is better to create a project for each client or to create a single project with a lot of space and there to store all the pages and databases. Please help me with this because I do not know what is the best practice

Comment: *What is better* is immediately subjective and asks for opinion, which makes the question off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience,
If your customer pays a fixed price for hosting it does not matter.
If you charge "pay as you go" then a separate project is the only way you can know how much exactly to charge.

Answer (score 0):

Like Ken says, it is very difficult to predict your needs with so little information.  One point to keep in mind: if you ever plan to turn over ownership of the project to the client, then having a separate project for each client will make life so much easier.